# Finding all possible and unique combinations

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

I'd like to solve simple resource assignment problem using Scala.
What I have now is a list of tasks and resources capable to do this tasks:

```
val t1 = List(1, 2)
val t2 = List(2, 3, 4)
val t3 = List(0)
val t4 = List(1, 4)
```

where `t` is just task and lists represent resources IDs. Let's assume that I can combine tasks IDs with resources IDs like that:

```
val a1 = List((1, 1), (1, 2))
val a2 = List((2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4))
val a3 = List((3, 0))
val a4 = List((4, 1), (4, 4))
```

where `a` represents assignments for particular task.

So the next step is to gather all assignments and flat them in one list:

`val assignments = List((1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), (4, 1), (4, 4))`

What I want to have here is all possible combinations which contains list of assignments where every task id is different.

```
val result1 = List((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 0), (4, 4))
val result2 = List((1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 0), (4, 1))
...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the number of tasks fixed at 4? if so this is pretty trivial:

```
val t1 = List(1, 2)
val t2 = List(2, 3, 4)
val t3 = List(0)
val t4 = List(1, 4)

val as = for {
  a1 ← t1
  a2 ← t2
  a3 ← t3
  a4 ← t4
} yield List((1,a1), (2, a2), (3, a3), (4, a4))

as foreach println
```

output is:

```
List((1,1), (2,2), (3,0), (4,1))
List((1,1), (2,2), (3,0), (4,4))
List((1,1), (2,3), (3,0), (4,1))
List((1,1), (2,3), (3,0), (4,4))
List((1,1), (2,4), (3,0), (4,1))
List((1,1), (2,4), (3,0), (4,4))
List((1,2), (2,2), (3,0), (4,1))
List((1,2), (2,2), (3,0), (4,4))
List((1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (4,1))
List((1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (4,4))
List((1,2), (2,4), (3,0), (4,1))
List((1,2), (2,4), (3,0), (4,4))
```

Comment: The number of available tasks is known in advance but not fixed. It depends on file which I read from.